# Xcode 8, should I update my project to recommended settings?

Tags: warnings, xcode8, updates, commit

When my project builds, XCode recommends that I update to recommended settings in a warning. When I try to update it, it says that my project has uncommitted changes. Should I still update?

Comment: Yes. Update the setting. Build and run. If everything is ok, commit your changes. Xcode has silly warnings in regards of uncommitted changes lately.